# IntelliJ IDEA build project in the morning

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1.3 and java/maven project.

When I come to work in the morning and try to run one JUnit test, it takes about 3 mins for IDEA to rebuild the project and then run JUnit. 2nd, 3rd etc. executions of JUnit are quicker as they do not require 3 mins rebuild.

Is it possible to create CRON job to run every 7am and execute that build so then I do not have to wait 3mins before running JUnit?

I tried to schedule maven build but it does not solve the problem. Maybe IDEA has separate casches or something.

Thanks

Comment: Try an _offline_ build, so maven does not get its 3rd party libraries reloaded. Actually there are several screws you may turn, like when to  update.

Comment: Also I would suggest to upgrade to most recent version of IDEA IntelliJ..

Comment: Anti-virus warming up?